# Magento Rest Api utilization

Tags: api, rest, magento

I want to access the REST API of magento through REST.I create oauth_consumer with consumer Key and secret from magento admin panel but i am **unable to get the access token** to access the data.
I am following below tutorials
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api & http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html

I am getting all products using /api/rest/products but unable to get customers list etc.
Guys please do needful , i am new bee in magento.

Comment: I create module for using [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/) and got oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

Answer (score 0):

The Products API in magento can be accessed by Guest but, this is not the case for Customers API. You have to authenticate the user as Customer or admin before you can access Customers API. To authenticate you can follow the tutorial available at [Magento Oauth Authorization](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html). The Admin authorization returns data of all the Customers and Customer authorization returns data of the customer who you authorized. For various authentications available on different types of API consumers, you can refer to [Magento REST API customer resource](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html).